# Self complementary graph with a pendant vertex

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that if a self-complementary graph contains a pendant vertex, then it must have at least another pendant vertex.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$, so it has $n(n-1)/4$ edges, just like its complement. Asume that there is only one pendant vertex $v$, so $d(v)=1$, it means that $G^c$ has a vertex $w$ with $d(w)=n-2$. Then $G$ must also have a vertex of degree $n-2$ and $G^c$ one of degree $1$.

I guess I can reach somehow a contradiction with the fact that $n=4k$ or $n=4k+1$, but I got stuck there.

Can you give me a **hint** please? Like "this fact may be useful..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very nice problem. I did not know it, but I find it hard to give a hint without giving away the full proof. Here is a try: consider the adjacency of the vertex of degree 1 and the vertex of degree $n-2$.

Here is the proof then.

Suppose there is only one vertex $v$ of degree 1.
Then there is also only one vertex $w$ of degree $n-2$.
Let $\phi$ be an isomorphism mapping $G$ to its complement.
Clearly $\phi(v)=w$ and $\phi(w)=v$.
But this implies that $v$ and $w$ are adjacent in $G$, if and only if they are adjacent in the complement.

This contradiction shows that there must be another vertex of degree 1.

Comment: Mmm, I don't know...$G$ must have $n-2$ vertices with degree greater or equal than 1...I still can't get it :'(

Comment: The proof is now added to the answer.

Comment: I have alredy thought something similar but I couldn't keep going because $v$ is a vertex of $G$ and $w$ is a vertex of $G^c$, if they are correspondent by $\phi$ then they must have the same degree, isn't that correct? I know this: we have $v$ of degree 1 in $G$, via $\phi$ we get $\phi(v)=v'$ of degree 1 in $G^c$, in a similar way for $\phi(w)=w'$. And those are unique...
Sorry, I'm very confused :/

Comment: $G$ and $G^c$ have the same vertices, they only have different edges. $v$ has degree 1 in $G$, but it has degree $n-2$ in $G^c$. For $w$ it is the other way around. Therefore $\phi(v)$ *must* be $w$ and v.v.

Comment: @Hermine If that doesn't cut it, I suggest simply trying to draw the graphs, focusing on $v$ and $w$.  First suppose that $v$ and $w$ are neighbors, and find the contradiction.  Then suppose they aren't neighbors - you'll reach another contradiction.

Comment: @Manual Lafond: thanks. Drawing may not be very obvious here, but the separation in two cases probably will make it easier to understand.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I was missing something very obvious! :/ Thanks all! :)

Comment: Excellent and concise proof!

Comment: so the problem can be generalized to the case of having multiple vertices of same degree in an self complementary graph